# How to hide a button after click

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Edited my code, sorry for that!**

I made a button using HTML, CSS and Javascript and I'd like to know to hide it when clicked.

Here's the HTML, it's supposed to play music when you click on play.

```
<audio id="myTune" src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/HappyBirthday.mp3"></audio>

<button type="button" onclick="aud_play_pause()">&#9658</button>
```

CSS

```
body { background: black; }
button {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: 0 5px gray;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  }

button:active {
  background: #DDDDDD;
  color: #222222;
  border-bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 3px #555555;
  margin-top: 2px;
  }
```

Javascript

```
function aud_play_pause() {
  var myAudio = document.getElementById("myTune");
  if (myAudio.paused) {
    myAudio.play();
  } else {
    myAudio.pause();
  }
}
```

Comment: Is that js part of your `aud_play_pause()` function?

Comment: Where's the element referenced in `document.getElementById("myTune")`? Where's your attempt at hiding the button?

Comment: I just edited the code, sorry

Answer (score 4):

Just use the **hidden** property of the button element.

Working example:

```html
<button onclick="hello(this)">
  Hey
</button>

<script>
  const hello = (element) => {
    element.hidden = true;
  }
</script>
```

Just to clarify what I did  there, I'm passing the reference to the element (`this`) as a parameter to the function which is triggered on click. When the function is called it reads the reference as `element` and sets the property `hidden` as true, so the browser will stop rendering it.

Comment: Would you please tell me how to use it on my code, I can't add it properly. Thanks for the answer though!!

Comment: Change `onclick="aud_play_pause()"` to `onclick="aud_play_pause(this)"`, add a parameter to the function declaration (ex: `function aud_play_pause(element)`) and call `element.hidden = true` inside the function.

Comment: I added a clarification the to end of my answer to explain it a little more in-depth.

Answer (score 1):

You can use style Properties
**Css**
1.display:none
2.visibility:none
**Js**
element.hidden = true;

```js
function hide(){

var button=document.getElementById('hide');
button.style.display="none";

}
```

```css
button{
display:block;

}
```

```html
<button id="hide" onClick="hide()">play</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: This is how you can use it in your code. You need to pass the reference to the element you want to hide.
Then
          `elem.style.display = 'none'`
Not sure your exact use case but this could be a start.

```js
function aud_play_pause(elem) {
  var myAudio = document.getElementById("myTune");
  if (myAudio.paused) {
    myAudio.play();
  } else {
    myAudio.pause();
  }
  elem.style.display = 'none'
}
```

```css
body { background: black; }
button {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: 0 5px gray;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  }

button:active {
  background: #DDDDDD;
  color: #222222;
  border-bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 3px #555555;
  margin-top: 2px;
  }
```

```html
<audio id="myTune" src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/HappyBirthday.mp3"></audio>

<button type="button" onclick="aud_play_pause(this)">&#9658</button>
```